# Can two people commit code to the same PR without maintainer privileges?

Tags: git, github

I am collaborating on the following [PR](https://github.com/rpearce/react-medium-image-zoom/pull/235) and wish to commit code to it but I don’t have maintainer privileges? Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: PRs are a GitHub thing, not a Git thing: add the tag [tag:github]

Comment: yes, two people can commit to the same branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull requests and feature branches are two separate concepts. A pull request is a request to merge a feature branch into a more centralised target branch (in this case, `master`). The feature branch is where the actual coding takes place.

More than one developer can indeed commit to the same feature branch... though this is generally considered to be bad practice, due to the potential conflicts. Instead, work should be divided up so that each 'feature' is small enough to only warrant one developer working on it. Most people follow a practice known as [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), though there is also a developing trend shifting towards a [Shift Left test strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-left_testing), which slightly alters the flow.

Multiple features can be worked on simultaneously, and GitHub will warn of any conflicts at the time you attempt to merge that particular feature branch back. Having said that, it is still a good idea to make sure you pull the latest changes from the target branch before attempting to merge back there.

If both developers *must* work on the same branch, then only the person who creates the pull request should require the relevant GitHub privileges; the pull request has *already* been created, and subsequent commits will automatically be reflected in the pull request. It is only at the point at which the pull request is merged that the code from the feature branch will copy over to the target branch, carrying all commits made on said feature branch up to that point with it.